# Rails 3 - association according own table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, primary-key

I have these two tables:

```
colors
- id
- name
- name_code

cars
- id
- manufacturer
- color_code_name
```

(in the columns `colors.name_code` and `cars.color_code_name` are the same values)

I would like to get all cars with the respective color. I tried to set up these associations:

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, :primary_key => "name_code"
end
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :color, :primary_key => "color_code_name"
end
```

But this is unfortunately doesn't working... I didn't specify yet this kind of association, so I am not really sure, if it's possible to do it...

I am gonna be grateful for every advise

Comment: I think you may just need to reverse where you've specified `name_code` and `color_code_name`. It's hard to be sure without knowing what error messages you're getting, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key :name_code
  has_many :cars, :foreign_key => :color_code_name
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key :color_code_name
  belongs_to :color, :foreign_key => :color_code_name
end
```

Comment: It is recommended to use `self.primary_key=` instead of `set_primary_key`.

Comment: Thanks jdoe. Changed as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add an = in the primary key assignment (for rails 3.1 anyway)

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :name_code
  has_many :cars, :foreign_key => :color_code_name
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :color_code_name
  belongs_to :color, :foreign_key => :color_code_name
end
```

Thanks for the answer. It was what I was looking for